# 802.11ac : Trying to obtain 1.7333 Gbps 160MHz

Tags: wifi, network-interface, intel, asus

I am trying to obtain maximum throughput between two Ubuntu nodes;  both with the 160MHz capable Intel Wireless-Ac 9260 card using an ASUS GT-AX11000 router.

> Ubuntu1--2meters--AX11000--10meters--Ubuntu2

In both 5GHz-1 and 5GHz-2 band (I am using the 5GHz-1 one) I have the router configured as follows :

- Wireless Mode : Auto
- 802.11ax HE frame support : Enabled
- Channel bandwidth : 160 MHz (Ticked Enable 160MHz)
- Control Channel : 100 (Ticked Auto selectchannel including DFS channels)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jeWi.png

In the router : `wl -i eth7 status` returns use of 160MHz channel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZsn3.png

In the nodes : `iwconfig` returns 1.7333 Gb/s bitrate

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9FXC.png

### Questions

In the GUI Wifi site survey, this is what I get, no sign of 160MHz Bandwidth, nor 802.11ac support :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKVvt.png

**Question 1 : Why am I not getting 160MHz or 802.11ac in the ASUS WiFi Radar site survey ?**

**Question 2 : Why are the Site Survey and the wl command incoherent ?**

I am using iperf to test the throughput

Usual command : `iperf3 -c 192.168.50.118 -R -b 2000M  -u`

As a result, the maximum throughput i got is around 400 Mbits/sec

```
Connecting to host 192.168.50.118, port 5201
Reverse mode, remote host 192.168.50.118 is sending
[  4] local 192.168.50.117 port 39988 connected to 192.168.50.118 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  37.8 MBytes   317 Mbits/sec  0.199 ms  1/4841 (0.021%)
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  39.2 MBytes   329 Mbits/sec  0.077 ms  0/5013 (0%)
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  40.9 MBytes   343 Mbits/sec  0.241 ms  1/5235 (0.019%)
^C
[  4]   3.00-3.75   sec  29.5 MBytes   331 Mbits/sec  0.085 ms  0/3771 (0%)
```

**Question 3 : How can I get maximum throughput ?**

`lshw -c network` returns : https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Yl0.png

`iw list` returns : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MehN.png

**Question 4 : What is it with the Intel AC 9260 returning only 20MHz channels ?**

Comment: All these questions are networking questions actually. We cannot also guide which software and wifi card was used for the site survey

Comment: Intel-Wireless-AC 9260 is the wifi card

Comment: why the openwrt tag, btw?

Comment: it's actually ASUSwrt

Answer (score 1):

As for 1) and  2) the AP/AsusWRT is probably only listening to other APs/other antenas, and not to it's own antenas during the ASUS site survey.  It has at least to put one of the antenas in monitor mode. Hence not seeing/ignoring itself, or at least only showing a partial version of the SSIDs it supports.

As for 3) for measuring the speed between the two Wifi clients, depending whether both points of that `iperf` are on not in same antenas, you have to multiply the 400Mbps by a factor between 2x and 4x. Also `iperf3` can benefit on using several streams with the `-P` option.

As for 3) and 4) WiFi quality depends on several points, from the drivers Linux quality, to the distance you have to the AP, to the interference you might have go from neighbours. Also, ac open source/Linux drivers are not famous for extracting the best performance from WiFi ac chipsets. So, the chipsets only going up to 5GHz - 20MHz is not that surprising.

Comment: Why would Intel provide a UNIX driver that doesn't work ? Would be a bad marketing hit for the AC 9260.
Thank you for your answer @Rui .
With parallel streams i got a maximum Throughput of 550 Mbits/sec . I'm still looking to use the 160MHz bandwidth.

Comment: It is not they do not work. It is the support is still weak and dealing with WiFi is full of not so well defined variables and a few surprises. As sooner you get that the less time you worry about getting full speed. Often it does not happen in much better supported systems. Thanks for the asuswrt pointer